# declaring variable to itself then followed by OR and function declaration

Tags: javascript

I found this piece of code

```
...
var $ZSIQLSDB = $ZSIQLSDB || function () {
...
```

I'm just curious why anyone would declare a function like this? doesn't the left side of the OR will always be falsy?

Comment: Run this code twice. The left side will not be falsy.

Comment: Assume there is a variable that is defined by some other script and you need to use it. But there are chances where it might not be available, so you do this. If it exists, use it as is. If not use the fallback

Answer (score 0):

This assignment will use the existing value of `$ZSIQLSDB` if it is truthy and otherwise `$ZSIQLSDB` will be assigned the function.